# np.zeros versus array allocation in C misunderstanding

Tags: python, arrays, c, numpy, intel

I need to use the `dsyev` function from `LAPACK` on a large real symmetric 2D matrix. I can use it from `scipy.linalg.lapack`, but it doesn't finish computing in reasonable time.

I can benefit from > 20 cores on a HPC cluster which has `intel 2020` suite as a module. Because reasons, I cannot just use the same python code as the one from my laptop inside on the cluster and set the environmental variable `MKL_NUM_THREADS=32` for example. **My only way forward is using C and Intel MKL for C.**

I studied the intel MKL example on how to use the `dsyev` function in C.

My 2D array in python is shape `(20160, 20160)` of `np.float64`. `20160 = 252 * 80`. I just write `T = np.zeros((20160, 20160), dtype=np.float64)`, then proceed to filling it according to my task. At the end I reshape it using `np.flatten(order='C')`, then save it to disk in either a `.npy` or a `.txt` format.

**Here I ask for your help:**

I am trying to read it from memory using C.
My elementary program works for small 1D array sizes, example `(20000,)` of C `double`s, but fails when actually trying to read the whole 1D array, to be then used with `dsyev`.
According to google: `250 * 80 * 250 * (64 bytes) = 0.32 gigabytes` and I do not know why I cannot use in my C program a 1D array of that size, for example.

My code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double arrayy[252*80*250];
    // double *arrayy = (double*) malloc(250*80*100*sizeof(double));
    printf("Hehe");
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("1D_array.txt", "rb");
    for ( int i = 0; i < 250*80 ; i++) {
        // fread(&(array[i]), sizeof(array[i]), 1, fp);
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", &arrayy[i]);
    }
    // fread(&(arrayy[0]), sizeof(double), 252*80*3, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 252*80 ; i++ ) {
        if (i % 1000 == 0)
            printf("Value at index %d is %f\n", i, arrayy[i]);
  }
}
```

I am using `gcc 9.3.0.17` inside a Windows Subsytem for Linux 1 (WSL1) on a Windows 11 with 16 GB of RAM.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**:

This, when compiled with `$ gcc -Wall test.c` and then `$./a.out` returns `$ Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and nothing else gets printed!

Comment: Your problem is probably the stack size. Local variables are allocated from the stack which is a memory area with some specific maximum size. Try making it global instead (if that works for you) or else use malloc

Comment: @user253751, thank you for your help. I tried to use malloc as in: ``double *arrayy = (double*) malloc(250*80*100*sizeof(double));``, but ``./a.out`` results in ``Segmentation fault (core dumped)``. I will try your other idea, but I do not know what you exactly mean by making it global. Putting  ``double arrayy[252*80*100];`` above ``int main()``, the same segmentation fault appears.

Comment: Check the malloc result to see if it actually allocated anything (check arrayy for NULL)

Comment: "Even for very small arrays allocated" - are you trying to access it like before? If `i` goes to `250*80` and you do `arrayy[i]` but `arrayy` has only 252 elements, then of course you get a segfault.

Comment: Can any of you make an answer as now it works with ``malloc`` with 250*80*250*80 elements of type double, and the instruction is written inside main()?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, arrays are allocated on the stack just like any other local variable, which is a relatively small area in memory compared to the heap.

This line `double arrayy[252*80*250];` probably leads to a stack overflow which appears as a segmentation fault. To keep in line with your Python code, you should dynamically allocate your array, like this:

```
double *arrayy = malloc(250*80*100*sizeof(*arrayy));
```

Note that [you don't need the cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and that you can do `sizeof(*arrayy)` instead of `sizeof(double)`.

Also note that in your code, you seem to alternate between 252 and 250 for no reason. You should probably just name the size of your array into a variable, like this:

```
const unsigned long arrayy_size = 252 * 80 * 252 * 80;
double *arrayy = malloc(arrayy_size * sizeof(*arrayy));
// [...]
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < arrayy_size; ++i) {
    // use arrayy[i]
}
```